# Show expanded relative path instead of single letters in tabs

Tags: vim

When I have multiple tabs open in `vim`, the path of the file is shown in the tab:

[image]

Notice that only the first character of the directories is used:

`p/c/game.js`

instead of

`public/controllers/game.js`

Is it possible to show the fully expanded path in the tab, using the full directory names instead of just their first letters?

Comment: The `tabline` option controls what's displayed in the tab headers. It's a little complicated though. See "Setting 'tabline'" section in the docs here: 
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html

`:h filename-modifiers` might be helpful as well.

Comment: Friendly reminder that your tab may have other spits open in it. So a buffer might be hiding in some tab. I find it often easier to use a more buffer-centric workflow and avoid tabs all together

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function! MyTabLine()
  let s = ''
  for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
    " select the highlighting
    if i + 1 == tabpagenr()
      let s .= '%#TabLineSel#'
    else
      let s .= '%#TabLine#'
    endif

    " set the tab page number (for mouse clicks)
    let s .= '%' . (i + 1) . 'T'

    " the label is made by MyTabLabel()
    let s .= ' %{MyTabLabel(' . (i + 1) . ')} '
  endfor

  " after the last tab fill with TabLineFill and reset tab page nr
  let s .= '%#TabLineFill#%T'

  " right-align the label to close the current tab page
  if tabpagenr('$') > 1
    let s .= '%=%#TabLine#%999Xclose'
  endif

  return s
endfunction

function! MyTabLabel(n)
  let buflist = tabpagebuflist(a:n)
  let winnr = tabpagewinnr(a:n)
  return fnamemodify(bufname(buflist[winnr - 1]), ':p')
endfunction

set tabline=%!MyTabLine()
```

This code is almost 100% from vim help (see `:help setting-tabline`). The only tweak is the use of [fnamemodify](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/40.html) in `MyTabLabel` to get the full path.